# Equivalent norms in $\mathcal{C}([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $E = \mathcal{C}([0, 1], \mathbb{R})$ seen as a vector space.

Let $F$ be a subspace of $E$ such that there exists a real number $A > 0$ verifying: $\forall g \in F, \forall x \in [0, 1], |g(x)| \leq A (\int_{0}^{1} g^{2})^{1/2}$.

How can we show that $F$ is a finite-dimensional vector space with $\dim(F) \leq A^{2}$ ?

I though about using an orthonormal set of vectors (for the usual scalar product) but I could not make it work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Well, since I defined $A$ before saying $\forall g$, it does show that A does not vary with the function, doesn't it ? And I'm not asking whether $F$ is or is not a subspace, since I actually assumed it. The problem is to show that it is finite-dimensional (and of dimension $\leq A^2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ is orthonotmal on $F$ w.r.t $L^{2}$ inner product. Then $ |\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_ig_i(x)|\leq A \|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_ig_i\|_2=A\sqrt {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |a_i|^{2}}$ for each $x$. This implies that $\sqrt {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |g_i(x)|^{2}} \leq A$. Squaring and integrating we get $n \leq A^{2}$.

I have used the following basic fact: $\sup \{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_ib_i: \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |a_i|^{2} \leq 1\}=\sqrt {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} |b_i|^{2}}$.

Comment: Excellent solution!